# how to establish connection between MSMQ(or any other MQ) and Azure Service Bus?

Tags: azure, activemq-classic, msmq, nservicebus, azureservicebus

I have a scenario, in which I want to send messages from MSMQ/ActiveMQ to Azure environment which uses Azure Service bus. Any ideas, how I can create Publisher/Subscriber model to publish messages into Azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following sample demonstrates how you can do this for MSMQ (both from sending and receiving): http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Brokered-Messaging-MSMQ-a31c6644

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using something like the [NServiceBus transport bridge](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/bridge/) which will abstract away the communication issues between two queuing systems. Here is [an example](https://docs.particular.net/samples/bridge/azure-service-bus-msmq-bridge/) on how to configure it to communicating between Azure Service Bus and MSMQ

Answer (score 0):

There's no automatic way. You should create a app that dequeue messages from your msmq, and send to Windows Azure Service Bus (Windows Azure Service Bus Queue/Windows Azure Service Bus  Topic).

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/service-bus-relay/